# Unsatisfied dependency exception when wiring interface in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have the following classes and interfaces in my spring webapp and I am trying to autowire them. Spring complains with the following exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository'; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.xyz.repository.EmployeeRepository' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

EmployeeController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;
}
```

EmployeeService Interface

```
public interface EmployeeService {

}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl class

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;  
}
```

EmployeeRepository interface

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends EmployeeRepositoryCustom, JpaRepository<Employee, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee>{

}
```

EmployeeRepositoryCustom interface

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

}
```

EmployeeRepositoryImpl class

```
@Component
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepositoryCustom{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

}
```

The config classes look like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super.registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);

        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

}
```

SpringConfig class

```
    @Configuration
    @Import(value = {DataSourceConfig.class, WebMvcConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xyz", 
        excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Configuration.class, type= FilterType.ANNOTATION))
    @EnableSpringConfigured
    public class SpringConfig {
        @Autowired
        Environment env;

    }
```

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong in autowiring. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using spring or spring boot? Did you have configuration class?

Comment: normal spring java config

Comment: Please paste code of your configuration class or xml config file.

Comment: You are apparently using Spring Data JPA but don't have a `@EnableJpaRepositories`... So no repository is created at runtime.

Comment: You are not auto-scanning proper packages. Paste the SpringConfig.java

Comment: @Vito added as required

Comment: @M.Deinum you nailed it! it was the issue... pls write it as an answer. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends EmployeeRepositoryCustom, JpaRepository<Employee, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee>{

}
```

Judging from the above repository definition I suspect you are trying to use [Spring Data JPA]. However only extending a Spring Data interface isn't enough you also need to enable it with the [`@EnableJpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.java-config) annotation. Put that on your `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories("your-base-package-here")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```